# Import donations from an external source using Form processor

Tags: contacts, contributions, import, data-import

We have a customised platform where we have been receiving donations before moving to CiviCRM. This platform will continue to be in use.

We would like to import all the donations and the contract data automatically on civicrm whenever it’s submitted. We would also like to send a receipt from civicrm whenever a donation submitted.

I have had a look at “Form Processor” extension and seems to be a viable option for our need. Is it possible to use for importing contribution? What is the risk of importing data this way? Any security concerns? Has anyone used Form processor for this kind of use case? Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We use the Form Processor at a few of our clients for scenario' s like yours. In most cases we use this in a configuration with CiviCRM on another server and outside traffic (including the Form Processor API request) coming in through CiviProxy (https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/).

For this we use the CiviMRF framework (https://github.com/CiviMRF/cmrf_core).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to import existing data with the form processor. Is that right?

If so it is possible because the form processor creates an API in CiviCRM and this API can be called with REST from external systems.

The API entity is FormProcessor and the action is the name of your form processor.

You need some bit of custom development which is the collection of the existing data and sending it to the CiviCRM api and that is where the CiviMRF framework comes into place.